# Is there a way of extend a table by a column with a constant as a summary value from another column i.e. minimum value?

Tags: kql

I want to extend a table with a column that is populated by a constant value which is a minimum of another column on the same table without getting a summarised/condensed output.

I have summarize route but it always return a single value.

Comment: Do you want the selection result to include an additional value, or indeed *extend a table with a (redundant?!) column*?

Answer (score 0):

assuming I managed to understand your question correctly, you could try this:

```
let _min = toscalar(T | summarize min(col_1))
;
T
| extend percentage = 100.0 * col_2 / _min // or any other usage of `_min`
| ...
```